# Mysql 5.7 .idb recover

Tags: mysql

I have to copy a database from another server (MySQL 5.7), and I have only .frm and .idb files.

I have done this several times, on MySQL 5.6, with those steps:

1. Create table structure
2. ALTER TABLE table_name DISCARD TABLESPACE
3. Copy .idb file in database folder
4. ALTER TABLE table_name IMPORT TABLESPACE

Now, when I try to import tablespace (and run ALTER TABLE table_Name IMPORT TABLESPACE) the server shuts down. I checked error.log, but I do not see errors.

If I start againg the server and try to import tablespaces, I receive an error
`#1813 - Tablespace table_name exists.`

Any suggestions?